# Firebase iOS - Track UITableView Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase on Swift. I'm trying to track what the user selected from UITableView.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!


   //Declare an array 
    fruits = ["Apple", "Pineapple", "Orange", "Blackberry"]
   //Method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
                FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventViewItem, parameters: ["user_name":usernameTextField.text!,
                    "fruits_user_selected" :fruits[indexPath.row]])

            }
```

But it doesn't track which fruit the username selected. After waiting for 24 hours, it only displays tracks from the event name `kFIREventViewItem`.

[image: Image of tracking events]

[image: No fruits were tracked]

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen did you ever get an answer for this or find another resource?